# How to convert Microsoft Authenticator Secret Code for use in other TOTP Applications

Tags: totp, authenticator

Microsoft Authenticator yields an apparent 9-digit base-10 value for its secret code. This format doesn't work with other TOTP applications, which seem to expect Base32 values.

Any suggestions for how to convert the authenticator decimal codes into something usable outside of a Microsoft authenticator application?

I tried simply converting the code to Base32 using the below function. It yields a 6-digit valid input for TOTP, but the codes generated with this Base32 value don't match what comes out of the Microsoft Authenticator application.

```
def encode(n):
    N = 32
    chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"
    return (encode(n//N)+chars[n%N]).lstrip("0") if n>0 else "0"

# Example:
# print(encode(100000000))
# C7LYIA
```

So I expect some other transformation is needed... Or is the "code" provided at setup just another one-time passcode, and if so, how can the secret code itself be retrieved?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I did not. I expect it is not possible. However, I did find that there is an alternative option to generate a standard TOTP token instead of the non-standard Microsoft authenticator token for my Microsoft profile. The standard TOTP token is a satisfactory alternative for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you try from on mobile phone browser, by choosing "I want to use a separate app" (this choice doesn't appear on a desktop browser).

I successfully set up two separate accounts from mobile.